# How to set label dojo widget in a tablecontainer programatically

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi have a dojo TableContainer

```
var consultaTC = new dojox.layout.TableContainer({
       id:'consultaTC',
       cols: 4,
       customClass: "labelsAndValues","labelWidth": "280x"
   }, dojo.byId("consultaTC"));
```

and a FilteringSelect widget

```
    var fsOrigen= new dijit.form. FilteringSelect{
       id: 'fsOrigen',
       label: 'Old Label',........

    });
```

this widget is load in a dojo TableContainer with addChild method.

```
consultaTC.addChild(fsOrigen);
```

I tried to change the label of the widget programmatically with `dijit.byId('fsOrigen').set('label','New label');`

but don't work...

The problem is that the html output for the label in the TableContainer is

```
<label for='fsOrigen'>Old Label</label>
```

so, the TableContainer overwrite the label property of the widget.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using? Can you create a fiddle with an example of your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call for set label, you should add:

```js
consultaTC.layout()
```